# R Change Date of timestamp based on the hour

Tags: r

I have a series of timestamps, and I want to make a new variable with values that have an hour value after 9am to be changed to the next day's date. If it is before 9am the date would remain the same.

```
2018-5-11 01:57:00  would remain 2018-05-11
2018-5-11 11:15:00  would change to 2018-5-12
```

Comment: Check out the `lubridate` package at https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/ -- you can use the `hour()` function to extract the hour from a timestamp as an integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution answers your question, however, it might be worth it to consider writing code such that the raw data aren't mutated; engineering / extracting new variables (e.g. hour of day, "after 9 am or no" etc) for subsequent aggregation/subsetting might make development and code revision easier (especially if you're going back and forth between the end and the beginning of the script frequently).

```
timestamps <- as.POSIXct(c('2018-5-11 01:57:00','2018-5-11 11:15:00'), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
mask <- as.integer(format(timestamps, "%H")) > 9
timestamps <- as.Date(timestamps)
timestamps[mask] <- timestamps[mask] + 1
timestamps
[1] "2018-05-11" "2018-05-12"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df$timestamp_cast <- ymd_hms(df$yourtimestamp_col)
df$desired_col <- NA
df[hour(timestamp_cast) < 9, desired_col := as.Date(timestamp_cast)]
df[hour(timestamp_cast) >= 9, desired_col := as.Date(timestamp_cast)+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how your timestamps are stored, but let's assume they are of type `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"`, as created by for example `lubridate::ymd_hms`.

Then we can use `lubridate` and `dplyr`. Note the use of `dplyr::if_else` to prevent conversion of the dates to numeric.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data.frame(dttm = ymd_hms(c("2018-5-11 11:15:00", 
                            "2018-5-11 01:57:00"))) %>% 
  mutate(hr = hour(dttm),
         dt = if_else(hr > 9, as_date(dttm + days(1)), as_date(dttm)))
```

Result:

```
                 dttm hr         dt
1 2018-05-11 11:15:00 11 2018-05-12
2 2018-05-11 01:57:00  1 2018-05-11
```